# How to Sort a String in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

how can I sort *characters* within a `string` *alphabetically*?

I know this:

```
sorted = String.Concat(sorted.OrderBy(c => c));
```

but that would sort `"bABa"` like this:

`"ABab"`

what I want is `"AaBb"`

Comment: Do your strings only include alphabetical characters? From 'a' to 'b' and from 'A' to 'Z'?

Comment: yes they do, thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Dmitry thanks for correcting OP's typo that actually ruined the whole question. It's a new flow in SO - users are posting questions with typos and answerers are not only answering but also editing their questions to make them 'right'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try *ignoring case*:

```
sorted = String.Concat(sorted
  .OrderBy(c => char.ToUpper(c)) // sort ignoring case
  .ThenBy(c => c));              // on tie, i.e. 'A' and 'a' upper first
```

Comment: Thank you for youre answer (:

Answer (score -1):

*Output :*  **aAbB**
*add below using statement*

> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] test = Regex.Split("bABa", string.Empty); // string split to an array 
        Array.Sort(test); // sort created string array 
        string sample = string.Join("", test); //rejoin string array
        Console.WriteLine(sample);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Oh, that's overcomplicated - to use _Regex_ to split a string into chars. That's like to use an airplane to reach your neighbor that lives just over the street :) string is already an _IEnumerable<char>_ so no need to do that